# Prevent plus sign from being encoded on form submit

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

So, I've got a search form on my site that is GET submitting to a third party site. One of the input values is for subdivision names, and the third party requires that it be the subdivision name with + symbols for spaces. So, my value is getting parsed and replacing the spaces with +'s, however, when submitting, the values get urlencoded by the browser and in turn don't get parsed by the 3rd party.. My first thought is that they're not doing their job by not decoding the values on their end... But before I begin the painful process of dealing with their customer support, I'd rather check here first and see if there's a way I can work around it.

EDIT: here's my code (urls have been removed)

```
<form action="IDXBroker" method="GET">
    <h2>IDX Quick Search</h2>
    <div class="element">
        <label for="pt">Property Type</label>
        <select name="pt" id="pt">
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <option value="1" selected="selected">Residential</option>
            <option value="2">Commercial</option>
            <option value="3">Lots and Land</option>
            <option value="4">Rental</option>
            <option value="5">Multi-Family</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="element" ng-controller="searchCtrl" class="city-search">
        <label for="city">City/Subdivision</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchTerm" ng-change="setShowResults()"/>
        <ul class="city-results" ng-show="showResults && searchTerm.length >= 3">
            <li ng-repeat="item in results | stringSearch:searchTerm"><a href="#" ng-click="selectCity(item)">{{item.data}}</a></li>
            <li ng-show="(results | stringSearch:searchTerm).length === 0 && searchTerm.length >= 3">No Results Found</li>
        </ul>
        <input type="hidden" name="{{searchType}}" value="{{searchTermValue.split(' ').join('+')}}" />
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <label for="lp">Min Price</label>
        <input id="lp" name="lp" type="number" value="200000" />
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <label for="hp">Max Price</label>
        <input id="hp" name="hp" type="number" />
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <label for="bd">Min Bedrooms</label>
        <input id="bd" name="bd" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <label for="tb">Max Bedrooms</label>
        <input name="tb" type="text" />
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="srt" value="newest" />
    <div class="buttons">
        <input type="submit" value="Search Now" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with some code ?

Comment: How is the form being serialised, are you doing that or just letting the browser do it when the form is submitted?

Comment: I'm letting the browser do it, but there's not a way around that, is there? Seems like it does it no matter what I try to do before hand, url encoding or replacing the spaces with +

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can force the browser to not encode the plus signs. As a workaround you could just reload the window with js. Something like

```
var id1value = document.getElementById('hp').value;
var id2value = document.getElementById('lp').value;
//repeat for all your inputs to build your string

var q = 'hp=' + id1value + '&lp=' + id2value;

window.location = 'http://IDXBrokerURL?' + q;`
```

add an onclick to the submit to run your js function. Then there is no encoding at all.

I'll get this encoding issue submitted to their developers support.